# I want to reduce the width of one of my flex-items in my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, vuejs2, vue-material

How would I reduce the width size of my levi link without affecting the other tabs?

This reason I want to this is that when I click on the space between levi and the rest of the links it goes to the page connected to the levi link. The width of the levi link is too wide. HOW do I reduce it?

In the image below the levi spans a large area of the navigation bar. I want to reduce it.

[image: This is the image]

[Adjust the width of the preview to see the effect of the css declarations](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m073hp/50/)

This is the HTMl

```
<md-whiteframe class = "main-toolbar ">

  <md-theme name = "teal">

      <md-toolbar id = "flex-container">

     <router-link id = "nav" class = "nav-link " :to = " { name: 'levi' }" style = " text-decoration: none;  color: #ffffff; background-color: red; ;         ">levi</router-link>


    <router-link class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Product' }" style = " text-decoration: none;  color: #ffffff; background-color: yellow;">Using levi</router-link> 

     <router-link  class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Support' }" style = " text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; background-color: green;"> Support </router-link>

         <md-button class = "md-raised md-button">

          <router-link id = "navbutton" style = " text-decoration: none; color: #429bf4;" class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'levi' }" > Create Account</router-link>


</md-button>

      </md-toolbar>


  </md-theme>

   </md-whiteframe>
```

This is the CSS

```
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        top : 1px;    
        width: 100%;
    }
    #flex-container, #nav {

        font-size: 55px;
        display: flex;
        flex:1;
    }


    #navbutton {
        text-transform: none;
        font-size: 19px !important;
        font-family: Heiti SC;
    }

    .nav-link {
/*        display: inline;*/
        font-family: Helvetica neue;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 19px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        margin:8px;
    }

    .md-display-2 {
        font-family: Heiti SC;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #container > .md-layout {
/*  background-color: #F9FBFB;*/
  min-height: 100px;
  border-color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
/*  border-style: dotted;*/
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
font-family: Heiti SC;

}

    footer {
        margin-top: 100px ;
    }

    .btnsubscribe {
         text-transform: none;
        font-family: Heiti SC;
        font-weight: bolder;
        min-width: 66px !important;
         min-height: 56px !important;
        font-size: 19px !important;
    }

    .md-layout #inputSubscribe {

    margin-left: 09px;
    width: 300px;
    }

    .md-layout h3 {
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: try giving max-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your `router-link` in a `div` and change css as given

```
<div id="abc" style="text-decoration: none;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: red;" class="nav-link">
    <router-link id="nav" to="[object Object]">levi</router-link>
</div>

#flex-container, #abc{        
    font-size: 55px;
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
}
```

also remove `cursor: pointer` to `.nav-link` and give it to

```
router-link { cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: Max-width drags all the links to the left when it specifies the maximum with of the levi link.

Comment: sorry, I mistook your question 'without affecting the other tabs?'

Comment: so you want to increase the other links width ?

Comment: No. I want to reduce the width of the levi link because when I click on the space between the levi links and the rest it routes me to the home page.This may be annoying for the user. I want the click area for the levi link to be less